# Isolating float values in imported csv file and inserting them into a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, csv, type-conversion

Essentially, I have a CSV file containing data comparing the speed and the elapsed time in seconds. This CSV file as a datatype is an object when I import it on Google Colab with Python.

Additionally, this CSV file was obtained using the game *Universe Sandbox 2* with its function of uploading CSV files of data that users want to obtain after analysing certain characteristics over a period of time during the game session. In my case it's the speed vs. elapsed time.

My goal is to isolate the floats contained in that data and inserting them into a numpy array for further graphical analysis.

Below is a text code sample of the data I have acquired:

```
"#Universe Sandbox - 34.0.3"
"#Sim=Solar System"
"#NumItems=1,StartTime=0,EndTime=284569725.789386,TimeSpan=85536000"
"#Id=4,Name=Earth"
"TimePassed (year),Body.RelativeSpeed (km/s)"
"6.33101469304518,29.56082498805"
"6.37894990067948,29.4462248148605"
"6.42980290356108,29.3587977892391"
"6.47565397173302,29.3165767083232"
```

For simplicity, I will end the text code as recommended by the comments.

Below are the libraries I have tried implementing including `pandas.to_numeric`, `apply()`, `astype(float)` etc.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv
```

If anyone could help me in more detail on this, then I would greatly appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for the last 1 1/2 weeks without further relevant improvements.

Comment: In your mind, what is the difference in ‘decimal’ values and ‘float’ values?  What is the reason behind the desire to convert?  What does “nothing worked” really mean?

Comment: Just now edited my question. I hope this somewhat improves my coherence on my question..

Answer (score 0):

Skip initial rows like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your file', skiprows=4)
```

Your data screen suggests column names are in row 5
Then you need to transform data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your file', skiprows=4, names=['data']) # data are str so transform them    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).to_list(),columns=['x','y']).astype('float')
# split columns . make another df . convert data to float
```

better version

```
df=pd.read_csv('your file', quoting=2,skiprows=4,names=['data'])
df1=df['data'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype('float64')
df1.columns=['x','y']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have now implemented this and checked for the datatype of the isolated floats. Apparently, they are objects..

Answer (score 0):

Don't post-process. Do this in one pass with `read_csv`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

content = r'''"#Universe Sandbox - 34.0.3"
"#Sim=Solar System"
"#NumItems=1,StartTime=0,EndTime=284569725.789386,TimeSpan=85536000"
"#Id=4,Name=Earth"
"TimePassed (year),Body.RelativeSpeed (km/s)"
"6.33101469304518,29.56082498805"
"6.37894990067948,29.4462248148605"
"6.42980290356108,29.3587977892391"
"6.47565397173302,29.3165767083232"
'''
with StringIO(content) as f:
    # From now on, 'f' behaves like a file you'd have opened normally

    df = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=f, engine='python',
        skiprows=4, sep=r'"|,', usecols=(1, 2),
    )
print(df)
```

```
   TimePassed (year)  Body.RelativeSpeed (km/s)
0           6.331015                  29.560825
1           6.378950                  29.446225
2           6.429803                  29.358798
3           6.475654                  29.316577
```